# Create slider like infinite scrolling with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create CSS slider infinite scroll, but without appending/adding/creating DOM elements. Infinite scroll as in when the last slide is reached, the first slide should be shown again after it.

I have a fixed width slide, so the use of slick and box slider plugin does not work for me.

```css
.slider-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider-wrap .slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slider-wrap .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">

  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Tried with jquery clone and some other ways..but nothing fruitful..

Comment: Can you show us?

Comment: When slider reaches last slide, I cloned and also appended to parent, but it keeps creating more and more dom elements..

Answer (score 5):

Here are two options:

- **clone the items**: you get a more natural approach (cloning isn't that bad). That's the system you would usually find on websites to add more content.
- **revert the position** scroll position to another position to make it seem the slider never ends. Beware this will not make the scroll bar smaller as the content of the slider never gets changed

---

### (a) Cloning

As you said you can clone the images.

The trick is to determine when the scroll has reached the end of the slider to clone more images in:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slider-wrap').scroll(function() {
    
    const slider = $(this);
          width = slider.innerWidth()
          scrollWidth = slider[0].scrollWidth;
          scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft();
    
    if(scrollWidth - width == scrollLeft) {
      slider.children().clone().appendTo(slider);
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider-wrap .slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slider-wrap .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>

</div>
```

---

And here's a demo:

```js
$(function(){$('.slider-wrap').scroll(function(){const slider=$(this);var $width=slider.innerWidth()
var $scrollWidth=slider[0].scrollWidth;var $scrollLeft=slider.scrollLeft();if($scrollWidth-$width==$scrollLeft){slider.children().clone().appendTo(slider)}})})
```

```css
.slider-wrap{white-space:nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;border:1px solid red}.slider-wrap .slide{display:inline-block;margin:5px}.slider-wrap .slide img{height:120px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="slider-wrap"> <div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTa4e2VF6cfou9oL0cc5OAzVTEbmAgFjIW2r-7lTkpOljG9k38N"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://nbocdn.akamaized.net/Assets/Images_Upload/2018/01/06/0060bbce-f2f2-11e7-bf60-029def90d6d6_web_scale_0.0542636_0.0542636__.jpg?maxheight=460&maxwidth=638&scale=both"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQr0xQ-gVF1Sy1a1sHoUyfGdrBwyz-5u0Tirkt-uNCKd-AzNXY1ww"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/29/15/34/kitten-2354016_960_720.jpg"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJLwVbVu6tjubsduR43je-Muk7p8lAKDu569GuL_yDWGzrZwp2"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRHeW6zNDdDQBwtpuu3RvLW1ihM3Za-OLBoOMRR_4z7GvwYor2eQ"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKeCmurlUrTtd4CjvXYskGVAUAiDq5X49iNb3XhOcMss2vN8c6"> </div></div>
```

---

### (b) A hack with scrollLeft

You could also go straight back to the first slide container by setting the `scrollLeft` to the position when it first added a new slide container:

```js
let firstPos = undefined;

$('.slider').scroll(function() {

  const slider = $(this);
        width = slider.innerWidth()
        scrollWidth = slider[0].scrollWidth;
        scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft();
        isEndOfSlider = (scrollWidth - width) == scrollLeft;
        numberOfWraps = slider.children().length;


  if(isEndOfSlider) {    
    
    if(numberOfWraps == 1) {

      firstPos = scrollLeft;
      slider.children().first().clone().appendTo(slider);

    } else {

      slider.scrollLeft(firstPos);

    }      

  }


});
```

```css
.slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider-wrap .slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slider-wrap .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slide">1
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">2
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">3
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">...
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">...
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">-2
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">-1
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here's a demo:

```js
let firstPos=undefined;$('.slider').scroll(function(){const slider=$(this);width=slider.innerWidth()
scrollWidth=slider[0].scrollWidth;scrollLeft=slider.scrollLeft();isEndOfSlider=(scrollWidth-width)==scrollLeft;numberOfWraps=slider.children().length;if(isEndOfSlider){if(numberOfWraps==1){firstPos=scrollLeft;slider.children().first().clone().appendTo(slider)}else{slider.scrollLeft(firstPos)}}})
```

```css
.slider{white-space:nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;border:1px solid red}.slider-wrap{display:inline-block}.slider-wrap .slide{display:inline-block;margin:5px}.slider-wrap .slide img{width:auto;height:120px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="slider"> <div class="slider-wrap"> <div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTa4e2VF6cfou9oL0cc5OAzVTEbmAgFjIW2r-7lTkpOljG9k38N"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://nbocdn.akamaized.net/Assets/Images_Upload/2018/01/06/0060bbce-f2f2-11e7-bf60-029def90d6d6_web_scale_0.0542636_0.0542636__.jpg?maxheight=460&maxwidth=638&scale=both"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQr0xQ-gVF1Sy1a1sHoUyfGdrBwyz-5u0Tirkt-uNCKd-AzNXY1ww"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/29/15/34/kitten-2354016_960_720.jpg"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJLwVbVu6tjubsduR43je-Muk7p8lAKDu569GuL_yDWGzrZwp2"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRHeW6zNDdDQBwtpuu3RvLW1ihM3Za-OLBoOMRR_4z7GvwYor2eQ"> </div><div class="slide"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKeCmurlUrTtd4CjvXYskGVAUAiDq5X49iNb3XhOcMss2vN8c6"> </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Here is the problem, the dom elements keep on adding..Not as in slider plugin where only give number of slides remain, but still have scroll functionality without adding dom elements.

Comment: *Not as in slider plugin where only give number of slides remain, but still have scroll functionality without adding dom elements* what do you mean? You haven't mentioned that in your question...

Comment: Please see the dom, it adds div when scrolled to last slide..And about the mention in the question..Sorry I missed that part..

Comment: @Optimus *it adds div when scrolled to last slide*, well isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Yes, but not this way..It should show the same first slide again without adding/creating new dom elements..

Comment: Please edit your question by stating exactly what you are looking for. I have already spent  15 minutes replying to you.

Comment: @Optimus, I believe **(b)** is the solution you're looking for.